# Comparing list of objects in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

This post may be duplicate one, apologies for that.

I have worked extensively in Java-6, now moving to Java 8. Is there an efficient way to rewrite the below logic in Java 8?

This compares list of objects with single object, returning `true` if some object in the list has a matching "Identifier" parameter value.

```
private boolean compareOrder(UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig givenDeviceConfig, List<UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig> masterConfigList) {
    boolean isValidService = false;

    for(UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig eachRecord:masterConfigList) {
        if(eachRecord.getIdentifier()!=null && givenDeviceConfig.getIdentifier()!=null) {

            if(eachRecord.getIdentifier().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(givenDeviceConfig.getIdentifier().trim()) ) {
                isValidService = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return isValidService;
}
```

Also if I want to compare two list, any suggestions please

```
 List<UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig> oneList = some value;
 List<UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig> twoList = some value;
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean compareOrder(UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig givenDeviceConfig, List<UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig> masterConfigList) {

    return givenDeviceConfig.getIdentifier() != null
            && masterConfigList.stream().anyMatch(
                    p -> p.getIdentifier() != null
                         && p.getIdentifier().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(givenDeviceConfig.getIdentifier().trim()));

}
```

.

```
private static boolean compareOrderLists(List<UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig> list1, List<UserOrderDTO.OrderConfig> list2) {

    return list1.stream().anyMatch(
            p -> p.getIdentifier() != null 
                 && list2.stream().anyMatch(
                        p2 -> p2.getIdentifier() != null 
                              && p2.getIdentifier().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getIdentifier())));

}
```

Comment: No need to check `givenDeviceConfig.getIdentifier()!=null ` inside the predicate.

Comment: @guleryuz. thanks. If other object also list. forEach will work inside anyMatch ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean compareOrder(OrderConfig givenDeviceConfig, List<OrderConfig> masterConfigList) {
    //do null and empty checks here
    return masterConfigList
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(o -> o.getIdentifier().equalsIgnoreCase(givenDeviceConfig.getIdentifier()));
}
```

You can use [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#isEqualList(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) for list comparison. If you don't want to include a library, there are plenty of answers on stackoverflow to compare `Collections`.